# Is it good to store as a variable for "if condition" in iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I am little bit confused about this.Dont bother about output.

```
L = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2]
>>>[i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == min(L)]
```

Here,Does `min(L)` call in each iteration ?or Is it good like this

```
L = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2]
m = min(L)
>>>[i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == m]
```

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Yes, it’s called each iteration.

Comment: @minitech won't things be optimized here?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Python doesn't know that `min` has no side effects. It has to be called each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy enough to check (IPython console):

```
In [9]: def foo(x):
              print "Called."
              return True


In [10]: [1 for x in xrange(10) if foo(x)]
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
Called.
      Out[10]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

As to function calls getting optimized, that is usually the turf of a Just In Time compiler. So in case of PyPy, after a set number of iterations, the compiler may decide that this is a hotspot and may try to optimize the internals of the function, but I don't think that such optimizations are powerful enough to reduce the complexity from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

Comment: is there any caching for `builtin` functions like `min` `max` ?

Comment: @itzmeontv I don't think so. PyPy does have a JIT and it _may_ optimize the HotSpot after it has run a couple of thousand times, but in general, I would not rely on any optimizations occurring necessarily.

Comment: It's possible that another thread is modifying `L` between calls. There are just too many variables for the interpreter to consider to automatically cache the result. If you know that `min(L)` will always be the same value, you need to save the result to a variable yourself.

Comment: I accepted the answer :). can you explain the why python doesn't cache it ?.Is its advantage like chepners comment only?any more ?

Comment: @itzmeontv @chepner raised one important point with external side-effects changing the value of the arguments. The bottom line is that is it really hard for the compiler/interpreter to know when a (return) value will change and when it will not. It is easy to come up with examples where the `L` argument is changed _while_ the list is being constructed through side-effects. There are some languages (like Haskell), where the compiler can reason _a bit more_ about the code and do such optimizations but not in Python.